# Stripe::InvalidRequestError (This customer has no attached payment source Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I've been receiving this error all day while trying to test customer accounts. Can you show me a way to get past it. I will post the contents of my subscriptions controller and routes.rb below.

Subscriptions_controller.rb

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:new]
  before_action :redirect_to_signup, only: [:new]

  def show

  end

  def new
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    if @subscription.active
      @stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@subscription.stripe_user_id)
      @stripe_subscription = @stripe_customer.first
    end
  end

  def create
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
           source: token,
           plan: "gbsubscriptionlevel1",
           email: current_user.email
    )

    current_user.subscription.stripe_user_id = customer.id
    current_user.subscription.active = true
    current_user.subscription.save

    redirect_to users_index_path
  end

  def destroy

  end

  private
  def redirect_to_signup
    if !user_signed_in?
      session["user_return_to"] = new_subscription_path
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```

_Stripe_form.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_tag subscription_path, id: 'payment-form' do %>
  <form action="/subscription" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>
          <span>Card Number</span>
          <input value="4242 4242 4242 4242" class="form-control" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label>
          <span>CVC</span>
          <input value="123" class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label>MM</label>
        <input value="12" class="form-control" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="01"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label>YYYY</label>
        <input value="2019" class="form-control" type="text" size="3" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="2020"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline" type="submit">Create Subscription</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Routes.rb

```
resource :subscriptions
```

subscription.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($("meta[name='stripe-key']").attr("content"))

  $('#payment-form').submit (event) ->
    $form = $(this)
    # Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', true
    Stripe.card.createToken $form, stripeResponseHandler
    # Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    false

stripeResponseHandler = (status, response) ->
  $form = $('#payment-form')
  if response.error
# Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text response.error.message
    $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', false
  else
# response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    token = response.id
    # Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token)
  # and submit
  #$form.get(0).submit()
  return
```

Server Log/Stacktrace

```
Started POST "/subscriptions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-10 20:24:22 -0500
Processing by SubscriptionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B7ErmlwhWi4unI+r6um3MbZjPwfixfAXi4SiHpOrTUXphOh9kt07cEbC5CuuodrrIDRx4/L05l3VkgS6r+tKGA=="}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1119ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Stripe::InvalidRequestError (This customer has no attached payment source):
  app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:19:in `create'


  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (55.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (58.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby217/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (129.1ms)
```

Breakpoint on request for form

```
 <h2 style="margin-top: 30px">Request</h2>

    <p><b>Parameters</b>:</p>
<pre>{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0WVA1LNXqv97iQ47UYgitLTiAQQxOGfAl/YatYy/CXM/UIMzfavLoRPXZbsVwE9uIrVP4CEJcYrJ4LwRsP8OLg=="}</pre>
    <div class="details">
        <div class="summary"><a href="#" onclick="return toggleSessionDump()">Toggle session dump</a></div>
        <div id="session_dump" style="display:none">
<pre>_csrf_token: "7jXD5878YV5oXmuAREht2pZXTuQQMRZKXhampDxAB10="
session_id: "c9c8419f0e529507fc786aa8241044bf"
warden.user.user.key: [[5], "$2a$10$BbVveau77t6o1fJOMKxiFO"]</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div class="summary"><a href="#" onclick="return toggleEnvDump()">Toggle env dump</a></div>
        <div id="env_dump" style="display:none">
<pre>GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=0"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2 style="margin-top: 30px">Response</h2>

    <p><b>Headers</b>:</p>
    <pre>None</pre>
</div>
<div id="console" data-mount-point="/__web_console" data-session-id="ac2f197d51af2911171590df30f981c7"
     data-prompt-label=">> " class=" console">
    <div class="resizer layer pos-absolute border-box"></div>
    <div class="console-outer layer pos-absolute border-box">
        <div class="console-actions pos-fixed pos-right">
            <div class="close-button button border-box" title="close">x</div>
        </div>
        <div class="console-inner">
            <div class="console-prompt-box"><span class="console-prompt-label">>> </span>
                <pre class="console-prompt-display"><span class="console-cursor"> </span></pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace as well?

Comment: I updated my question to include the server log.

Comment: Do you see a javascript error? It looks like the stripeToken is never getting inserted into the form prior to posting.

Comment: I see nothing in my debug console.

Comment: I have "#$form.get(0).submit()" commented out. I wonder if that may be the cause? It's not still not working.

Comment: I encourage you to break just after the $form.append and verify that the stripeToken is set and that the input is in the dom. You'll note that the params to #create do not include that field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103155/discussion-between-andynu-and-daniel-w).

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that might point to the problem. But, the create method is where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripe::InvalidRequestError (This customer has no attached payment source)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348209/stripeinvalidrequesterror-this-customer-has-no-attached-payment-source)

Comment: I made changes to the code, but the error still persist.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching. I found the answer.

The version of jquery that's on the page is 1.3.2 which `.prop` isn't available for which is the reason for this error.

If you don't want to upgrade your version of jquery you can replace `.prop` with `.attr`:

```
$form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

becomes:

```
$form.find('button').attr('disabled', true);
```

Let me know if that helps.