# Stripe::InvalidRequestError (This customer has no attached payment source)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

There seems to be a problem with sending customer data and token back to Stripe's server. I'm currently using the test api to make dummy transactions. But, I cannot get past this point for no reason at all. I've tried everything to fix this error. I will post the code and error message below.

Subscriptions_Controller.rb

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:new]
  before_action :redirect_to_signup, only: [:new]

  def show

  end

  def new
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    if @subscription.active
      @stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@subscription.stripe_user_id)
      @stripe_subscription = @stripe_customer.subscription.first
    end
  end

  def create
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :source => token,
        :plan => "gbsubscriptionlevel1",
        :email => current_user.email
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_subscription_path

    current_user.subscription.stripe_user_id = customer.id
    current_user.subscription.active = true
    current_user.subscription.save

    redirect_to users_index_path
  end

  def cancel_subscription
    @stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(
        current_user.subscription.stripe_user_id
    )
    @stripe_subscription = @stripe_customer.subscription.first
  end

  private
  def redirect_to_signup
    if !user_signed_in?
      session["user_return_to"] = new_subscription_path
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```

_stripe_form.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_tag subscription_path, id: 'payment-form' do %>

  <form action="/subscription" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>
          <span>Card Number</span>
          <input value="4242 4242 4242 4242" class="form-control" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label>
          <span>CVC</span>
          <input value="123" class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label>MM</label>
        <input value="12" class="form-control" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="01"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label>YYYY</label>
        <input value="2019" class="form-control" type="text" size="3" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="2020"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary-outline" type="submit">Create Subscription</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <% end %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
</div>
```

subscription.js

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_tmBNNUvHTmtWXLhSL1q647iH');

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');

    if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#payment-form').submit(function (event) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

stripe.rb

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_TEST_SECRET_KEY"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That response typically arises after you try to attach a Subscription to someone with no card token attached.  From your code, I'd hazard a guess that you're running into a CardError and then despite that, trying to attach a Subscription anyway, which will not work.

Comment: I understand that there is no card token, but how do I add one?